# How Resize search view width with animation, when toolbar collapse [ADNROID]

Tags: java, android, kotlin, searchview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Hello guys I have search view in collapsing toolbar, I want to resize searchView width when toolbar collapse, for example, when toolbar is not collapsed search View width is "match_parent" and when user will scroll down and toolbar collapses search View should width should became  for example 200dp . how can I achieve this?

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/black">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="15dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:clickable="false"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:text="TITLE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:layout_width="27dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_boy_24">
            </com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_home"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadas"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**here is gif of my app**
https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-7e95a858c4.gif

Answer (score 1):

You can resize your search view programatically when your toolbar is collapsed.

Try this :

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.search);
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (verticalOffset == 0)
        {
           // Fully expanded
           searchView.getLayoutParams().width = CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        }
        else
        {
           // Not fully expanded or Collapsed
           searchView.getLayoutParams().width = dpToPx(200);
        }
    }
});
```

Here we are using a function to change dp into px as width is taken in pixels.

**dpToPx(int dp) :**

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    float density = this.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics()
            .density;
    return Math.round((float) dp * density);
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, eyesterday I did the same and it is working fine, but little bit weird because there is no animation, width size changes very straight , do you have any solution for that ? I need to add some animation